# Cannot Initialize Vendor Bill with the Vendor Payment Object in Boomi

Tags: netsuite, boomi

I am using Boomi to pass data into NetSuite. When I use the execute - initialize function on the vendor payment object and set the type to vendorBill I get an error. Here's what I'm seeing:

XML file sent to NetSuite

```
<InitializeRecord>
 <reference type="vendorBill" internalId="125056"></reference>
</InitializeRecord>
```

Error Message I'm receiving:

"Failed processing original documents iOi in the connector: java.lang.Exception: Unable to execute initialize. Must define valid Initialize Reference Type. Found: vendorBill Valid values are the following: [employee,vendor,vendorReturnAuthorization]"

According to NetSuite documentation the options I should have for initialize are:
employee,vendor,vendorBill.

I need to initialize the Vendor Bill, is there any reason why this isn't working, or a known workaround? Thanks! (Note that all other processes using initialize for other objects are using the same connector and are working properly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an unresolved bug in Boomi: BOOMI-30118.  It's a defect in the code where VENDOR_RETURN_AUTHORIZATION should be VENDOR_BILL.  There are 2 alternative solutions for this:

1. Use the SOAP connector to make the initialize request.  Your account manager should be able to get you a temp license to use the SOAP connector until the built in Netsuite Connector bug is resolved.
2. An initialize isn't technically necessary.  It won't be quite as simple, but you should be able to get all required fields through queries or gets, then map the create request directly.